# Dictionary from other dictionary grouping by object value field using linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a `Dictionary<ulong,Terminal>` called `TeminalDictionary` in my program, where `Terminal` has the next props:

```
public class Terminal
{
    public string TAC { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public uint Freq { get; set; }
 }
```

So, for that Dictionary, I want to make another one `Dictionary<string,ulong>` suming all the frequencies for every Manufacturer, so the dictionary key is `Terminal.Manufacturer` and the value is `Sum(Terminal.Freq)` with the same Manufacturer.

I tried this expression:

```
var pieDictionary = TerminalDictionary
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value.Manufacturer)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Sum(v => v.Value.Freq));
```

but it says that I'm trying to add an element with the same key, so I'm a little bit lost...

Regards!

Comment: Keys in a dictionary have to be unique. Manufacturer is not a good choice as it's likely not unique. The error is telling you that you're trying to add a duplicate key.

Comment: @Equalsk That's why I want to sum all the Freqs with the same Manufacturer, to have uniques Keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to provide the key in the new dictionary as well, which in your case is the key of the group. Given that you don't appear to need the keys within the *original* dictionary, I'd write this as:

```
var pieDictionary = TerminalDictionary.Values
    .GroupBy(x => x.Manufacturer)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(v => v.Freq));
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me the same error: "The dictionary already has an element with the same key."

Comment: @FernandoGallegoFernández: That shouldn't be possible. You're sure you included the `g => g.Key`? There should only be one grouping per key. It would help if you'd provide a short but complete example in the question, so that we could validate our answers...

Comment: Now I have an error that key can't be null, so I added `.Where(z=>z.Manufacturer!=null)` before the `GroupBy()`, I'll notice you when it works to approve your answer

Comment: @FernandoGallegoFernández: Given that you never mentioned that the manufacturer can be null, I don't think it makes sense for that to be part of the answer. If you need to handle that, I suggest you add it to the question - although it doesn't feel like it's logically part of the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can i suggest you a different approach? You could use a [`Lookup<tkey,tval>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var manufacturerFreqs = TeminalDictionary.Values
    .ToLookup(t => t.Manufacturer, t => (int)t.Freq);
int freq = manufacturerFreqs["Manufacturername"].Sum();
```

A lookup is similar to a dictionary and is as efficient, but it allows "duplicate" keys since the value is an `IEnumerable<TVal>` so you can query it.

So it's possible to store the complete object as element and get the sum of `Freq` anyway:

```
var manufacturerTerminals = TeminalDictionary.Values.ToLookup(t => t.Manufacturer);
int freq = manufacturerTerminals["Manufacturername"].Sum(t => (int)t.Freq);
```

This makes this collection more flexible, reusable and powerful.

MSDN:

> A `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` resembles a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The
>   difference is that a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` maps keys to single
>   values, whereas a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` maps keys to collections of
>   values. You can create an instance of a Lookup by
>   calling `ToLookup` on an object that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.